# Python multiprocessing stuck due to memory error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fork, spawn

The following script starts four subprocesses which tries to allocate more than 1/4 of the available memory.

```
import time
import numpy as np

def func(arg):
    try:
        print("Start allocating: "+str(arg))
        a = np.full((40, 1024, 1024,128),1.)
        print("Done allocating: "+str(arg))
        time.sleep(1)
        return arg
    except:
        print ("error")
        
if __name__=='__main__':

    import multiprocessing
    with multiprocessing.get_context('spawn').Pool(4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(func, range(4))
    print (results)
```

I would like the processes, which fail to allocate `a`, to print `error` and return `None`, but on my linux system they get stuck in

```
File "/home/test/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 302, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
```

If I increase the size of `a` to 160 (more than available) then all subprocesses prints `error` and return `None` as they should.

I have tried with both `fork` and `spawn` (as in the script), both with with same result

On Windows, it works